# Why VS suggests me to add this class reference as static when it isn't?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, static, roslyn

I was wondering why IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.5 is actually suggesting me adding this class reference as static [since](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-classes):

- Hasn't got any private constructor
- Hasn't got any static methods
- Hasn't got any static members
- On the class which is referencing this no-static class I'm just accessing the public `enum` ("Modo")

Class's code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Formularios
{
    public class Tipos
    {
        public enum GridControlMenusEdicion
        {
            Predeterminado,
            Siempre,
            Nunca
        }
        
        public enum Modo
        {
            Nuevo,
            Modificacion,
            Consulta
        }

        public enum TipoCampo
        {
            Texto,
            Fecha,
            Numero,
            SiNo
        }

        public enum EstadoEntidad
        {
            Nueva,
            Modificacion
        }

        public enum RangoDatos
        {
            Hoy,
            Ayer,
            EstaSemana,
            SemanaPasada,
            EsteMes,
            MesPasado,
            Ultimos3Meses,
            AnoEncurso
        }

    }

    class RangoDatosProvider
    {
        
        public Dictionary<Tipos.RangoDatos, string> DiccionarioRangoDatos()
        {
            return new Dictionary<Tipos.RangoDatos, string>
            {
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.Hoy, "Hoy" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.Ayer, "Ayer" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.EstaSemana, "Esta semana" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.SemanaPasada, "Semana pasada" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.EsteMes, "Este mes" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.MesPasado, "Mes pasado" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.Ultimos3Meses, "Últimos 3 meses" },
                { Tipos.RangoDatos.AnoEncurso, "Año en curso" }
            };
        }

        public string GetTextoLoadingRangoDatos(Tipos.RangoDatos seleccionUser)
        {
            switch (seleccionUser)
            {
                case Tipos.RangoDatos.SemanaPasada:
                    return "la " + DiccionarioRangoDatos()[seleccionUser].ToLower();
                case Tipos.RangoDatos.Ultimos3Meses:
                    return "los " + DiccionarioRangoDatos()[seleccionUser].ToLower();
                case Tipos.RangoDatos.AnoEncurso:
                    return "este año";
                default:
                    return DiccionarioRangoDatos()[seleccionUser].ToLower();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class which is referencing the previous code (used on the constructor):

```
using Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Formularios.Configuracion
{
    public partial class frmConfiguracionPerfilEmail : frmBase
    {
        private readonly PerfilEmailGestion _perfilEmailGestion = new PerfilEmailGestion();
        private readonly HashSet<string> _aliasExistentes;

        public frmConfiguracionPerfilEmail(PerfilEmail mailSettings, HashSet<string> aliasExistentes, Modo modo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Inicializar(mailSettings);
            _aliasExistentes = aliasExistentes;
            Modo = modo;
        }

    }

}
```

If I call IntelliSense for fast-adding references/usings it suggests me two options:

- a) "using static Formularios.Tipos"
- b) "Modo" as constructor parameter would become "Tipos.Modo"

Choosing `a)` would lead to adding a static reference which I don't get why.

Choosing `b)` would lead to adding the full namespace reference. I personally always try to remove all type qualifiers to simplify reading the code.

Any light thrown into clarifying this will be quite welcome.

P.S: Sorry for not translating the code, but I wanted to focus on the "why" and not the content itself. **The inherited class is not referencing** the "no-static" `Formularios.Tipos` class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because in your `frmConfigurationPerfilEmail` you don't have an instance of `Tipos`.
So what IntelliSense is trying to tell you that you access the public properties of `Tipos` either statically or by the class namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the suggestion is not to add a "class reference as static", but rather a "[static import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)".

`Modo` is not available to your code they way you're referencing it in your `frmConfiguracionPerfilEmail` constructor.  It's nested within the `Tipos` class, so it's not available as-is.

Suggestion 1 makes all static members and nested types of the `Tipos` class usable without having to qualify them, e.g. `Modo` instead of `Tipos.Modo`.

Suggestion 2 will not, as you said, qualify it with the full namespace.  `Formularios` is a namespace; `Tipos` is a class.  It's only suggesting qualification by the class name.  It doesn't need the namespace because the `frmConfiguracionPerfilEmail` class where it's being used is already under the `Formularios` namespace (`Formularios.Configuration`) so `Tipos` can be referenced without namespace qualification.

If you really want to simplify reading the code, as you say, then start by un-nesting those enums.  Nested types have their uses but using a class as nothing more than a container for other types is excessive.  Namespaces are there for that purpose.  Put the enums directly under the `Formularios` namespace.  Or, put them in a `Formularios.Tipos` *namespace* if you want them grouped somehow.

```
namespace Formularios.Tipos
{
    // enums
}
```

And if you do that, make sure you do this:

```
using Formularios.Tipos;
```

This would be the equivalent of doing `using static Formularios.Tipos;` with your current setup.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and for the tips. It makes complete sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your "RangoDatosProvider" class has no reason to be an instance class; it only operates on parameters and enums, meaning there is nothing in the class that can change state.

i do not know which code analysis ruleset you are using, but several hold the reasoning that "if it doesn't *need* to be instance, it is better off being static".
whether you agree with that is up to you, of course, but this is why it is recommended to you by visual studio